# Alcohol and acetic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

I recently did an experiment putting alcohol and acetic acid with conc. Sulfuric acid and heating it up, then i recondense the CH3COOC2H5. After that I put in some water and then NaCl solution I see some semi-transparent and red precipitate, can someone explain what it is

Comment: Likely contamination